# Not able to locate DropTarget ocean control

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am trying to implement custom UI for my workstep(for a plugin in ocean). I want to use the DropTarget Ocean control in its form.But even after adding reference to Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.Controls I am not able to locate the Ocean Toolbox in VCSE and hence the DropTarget control.

It seemed for DropTarget control I need Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.dll, I cant find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Schlumberger\Petrel 2012\Public folder

Please help.

Comment: Try not to tag your Ocean questions with C# and .Net. This will give it not needed attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is part of Slb.Ocean.Petrel.dll.

Answer (score 0):

The Ocean controlls are under the library Slb.Ocean.Petrel and Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI.Controls

In visual Studio you have to clic in the Tools menu, and select the Choose toolbox items.

In the show up window, click in Browse and look for the libbraries in the Petrel/Public folder and the controls will add in the General tab at the toolbox.

Hope it will help!